# Querying nested documents using Mongoose not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to filter using multiple items in a nested object in mongoose. The model is like this:

```
{
    name: String
    ...
    links: {url: String, canQuery: bool}
}
```

So I know you can filter by using

```
User.find({'links.url':{$ne:req.params.query}}, function(err, foundUsers){
   // ---
});
```

but I need to verify 2 paramaters, 1 the url and 2 the canQuery. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
User.find({links:{url: {$ne:req.params.query}, canQuery: true}}, function(err, foundUsers){
   // ---
});
```

How can I filter by multiple properties in a nested object

Answer (score 0):

You can query an embedded document in mongoose like this

```
User.find({'links.url': {$ne:req.params.query}, 'links.canQuery': true}}, function(err, foundUsers){
   // ---
});
```